# Using the Layoutservice with a virtualFolder setup

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 9.3 JSS with a `virtualFolder` site setup. My JSS site is located at `/jss` while there is another (MVC) site running at `/`.

When running `jss start:connected` I get "Placeholder not found". This is caused by the fact that the call to the Layoutservice uses the root content item of the MVC site (at `/`). (manually changing the item id  gives the correct result)

Adding the site name, e.g. `&sc_site=jss` also solves it.

Is it possible to configure the item or site name passed to the Layoutservice using JSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding `sc_site: config.jssAppName` to the `RouteHandler.js` query string parameters.

Edit `RouteHandler.js`:

```
...
function getRouteData(route, language) {
  const fetchOptions = {
    layoutServiceConfig: { host: config.sitecoreApiHost },
    querystringParams: { sc_lang: language, sc_apikey: config.sitecoreApiKey, sc_site: config.jssAppName },
    fetcher: dataFetcher,
  };
...
```

Comment: More info on customizing the Layout Service call (including query string params) is available in the JSS Guides
https://jss-docs-preview3.herokuapp.com/guides/code-patterns/routing#customizing-route-handling